# Dropdown widget to generate multiple lines in graph

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook, widget, country

In Jupyter Notebook I am struggling to find a way to generate multiple lines based on the values in a vector.
Here is my code:

```
Year = [0,1,2,3,4]
CH = [5,10,20,30,40]
DE = [15,20,25,30,45]
US = [0,10,20,40,60]
plt.plot(Year, US,color='red', marker='o')
```

This generates a graph with the values for the US. I want a widget (dropdown menu) that let the user select the country of his choice (CH,US,DE) and which generates a new line in the graph.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ipywidgets` module.

In the following code fragment the data is stored in a list and the dropdown options correspond to the list index values.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Year = [0,1,2,3,4]
data = [[5,10,20,30,40], [15,20,25,30,45], [0,10,20,40,60]]

w = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=[('CH', 0), ('DE', 1), ('US', 2)],
    value=2,
    description='Country:',
)

display(w) # display the widget

plt.plot(Year, data[w.value], color='red', marker='o')
```

**EDIT:** Screen grab added.

[image: Screen capture of functioning code.]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it does not generate a dropdown list where the user can select between CH. DE or US. Don't know if this is an issue on my side... It only generates a plot with the values for CH.

Comment: My bad - I forgot the line to display the widget. Code has been amended.

Comment: Still when I change the country in the dropdown list it has no effect on the graph

Comment: Did you place the `plt.plot()` line in another cell?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I realized I have to re-run the `plt.plot()` line each time I want to change the country. Is there a way to make it automatic? As soon as I change the country from the list, the graph gets updated?